# minsdk problem in android

Tags: android

I developed application on 1.6.in manifest i gave:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>.
```

When I run application in android 1.5 version.i am getting error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable/title_bar_shadow.9.png
```

If I make one drawable folder and keep the images inside drawable. It is working is it good for make one drawable folder with android 1.6.

How to make it run on android 1.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you place `the title_bar_shadow.9.png`?
If your 9patch is in a `drawable-[ldpi|mdpi|hdpi]` folder it will not work.

Check [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ff22f6e42a4a46d2/4201a20aaa23069d?show_docid=4201a20aaa23069d&pli=1#) thread to see how to fix it.

Comment: i am not placing png file any where if i run apps in 1.5 emulator it is showing error.if i run application in 1.6 it is working fine .i found problem came from drawable folder.how can i resolve this

Answer (score 1):

Please move the images under [drawable-mdpi] to [drawable] folder. This should solve your problem.